# Is this a good bind method?

Tags: javascript

```
Function.prototype.bind = function() {
    var $this = arguments[0];
    return this.apply($this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
};
```

Is it good enough to use in real-world application?

Comment: Why not just use functionName.call(this, arguments)?

Comment: I think some libraries have a bind function that allows you to bind the scope of a function that gets called *later*, such as an event callback.  But above you are executing it right away. Which is your intent?

Comment: Your function is incorrect, @David - it should return a **function**, not the result of **calling** the function. That is, it's incorrect if you want it to work like ".bind()" works in browsers that support it natively.

Comment: MDC lists a [compatibility implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility), along with explanation, of the now-built-in `bind` method that you may find of interest.

Answer (score 4):

No. There are a few things I don't like about this code, and a few reasons why it won't work.

First, most people don't assign arguments that way. It takes up extra space for no extra effect. Only use the arguments variable if the variable names should change depending on the number of arguments/type of arguments. To assign `$this` you should do..

```
Function.prototype.bind = function($this) {
```

Second, bind should return a function. Your's returns whatever `this` returns. Your function acts more like a `Function:call` then a `Function:bind`.

What you need to do to fix it, is make it return a function that when run will return whatever the function returns.

Try this:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function($this) {
    // `this` changes inside the function, so we have to give it a safe name.
    var self = this;
    return function () {
        return self.apply($this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
};
```

Also, more modern browsers have the ECMAScript 5 standard of this function built in. The function is written in plain JavaScript, so for older browsers, just include this [code suggested by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility):

```
if ( !Function.prototype.bind ) {
    Function.prototype.bind = function( obj ) {
        var slice = [].slice,
            args = slice.call(arguments, 1),
            self = this,
            nop = function () {},
            bound = function () {
                return self.apply( this instanceof nop ? this : ( obj || {} ), args.concat( slice.call(arguments) ) );
            };
        nop.prototype = self.prototype;
        bound.prototype = new nop();
        return bound;
    };
}
```

Comment: I think you need a `return` inside the returned function - otherwise any returned value from the actually-called "real" function would be lost.

Comment: Thanks. I always forget about that. xD